# How to limit macOS process to a single instance in plain C++?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm using the following Swift code to limit my GUI app on macOS to a single instance:

```
func IsAnotherInstanceRunning() -> Bool
{
    let thisApp = NSRunningApplication.current
    let thisBundleID = thisApp.bundleIdentifier
    let thisPID = thisApp.processIdentifier
    
    let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
    
    let apps = workspace.runningApplications.filter { (app) -> Bool in
        
        if(app.bundleIdentifier == thisBundleID &&
           app.processIdentifier != thisPID)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    };
    
    //Found any?
    if(apps.count > 0)
    {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}
```

I also have a console application written in C++. How can I do the same in pure C++?

Mainly how do I call anything related to `NSRunningApplication` and `NSWorkspace`?

Comment: By the way, there's a few things that could be simplified in your example. Don't use `if b` with `return true` and `return false`. Just return `b`. E.g. `return apps.count > 0`. Also, you don't need to filter just to check for emptiness. There's `contains(where:)`, which you can just use like: `return workspace.runningApplications.contains(where: { app in app.bundleIdentifier == thisBundleID && app.processIdentifier != thisPID })`

Comment: @Alexander: Thank you. Swift is not my language. I just started working with it less than a month ago.

Comment: No worries, I figured it'd be good to know, which is why I chimed in. The part about not checking booleans only to `return true` or `return false` applies equally to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use named mutexes to achieve what you want.
You create a mutex with a specific name. If mutex already exists you quit.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html

For crossplatform implementation make sense to take a look on https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-synchronization
named_mutex.

Comment: Thanks. But will macOS remove such mutex automatically if my process crashes?

Comment: The mutex object is destroyed when there are no more handles referencing it.
Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379817/boostinterprocessnamed-mutex-vs-createmutex

Comment: I know that it is destroyed in Windows (like your link shows) but I'm not sure about macOS/BSD?

Comment: `pthread_mutexattr_get/setpshared` will require setting up some shared memory, but, yes, if your process crashes or terminates for any reason, macOS (or any POSIX compliant OS) should close/remove all resources your process requested of it.  If it doesn't, it's a bug in the OS.

Comment: Look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808431/boost-interprocess-named-mutex-remains-acquired-after-a-crash